# Xamarin Forms - Google SignInButton in iOS Missing Labels

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing Google authentication in my app. I've got the sign in process working, however for some reason the Google button is not rendering properly. The text and icons are missing.

Here is my custom renderer code for iOS:

```
using System;
using Google.SignIn;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using APP.iOS.Renderers;
using APP.View.Session;
using UIKit;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(GoogleLoginButton), typeof(GoogleLoginButtonRenderer))]
namespace APP.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class GoogleLoginButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<Button, SignInButton>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            var loginButton = new SignInButton ();
            if (e.NewElement != null)
                SetNativeControl (loginButton);
        }
    }
}
```

and my PCL placeholder file:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace APP.View.Session
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Empty Implementation of GoogleLoginButton, will be implemented in Platform libraries.
    /// </summary>
    public class GoogleLoginButton : Xamarin.Forms.View
    {
        public GoogleLoginButton ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output below. You can see that the Facebook button renders fine, but for some reason the Google button does not. They are using identical renderers but for the differences in types.

[image: Here's the output].

I've tried subclassing from Xamarin.Forms.View instead of .Button but it didn't have an effect. Neither did changing the tint colour. As far as I can tell there's some component of the rendering logic that isn't working well with Xamarin Forms, but I don't think the source code is available to dig into deeper.

I am proceeding with rolling my own button and calling the `SignInUser()` method directly, but I'm curious if there's any quick fixes for this.

Versions and stuff:

- Xamarin.Forms 1.5.1.6471
- Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn 2.3.1.0-beta3
- Xamarin.Google.iOS.Core 1.1.0.0-beta3
- Xamarin Studio 5.9.8
- Xamarin iOS 9.1.0.27

Comment: Can you show us some of the SignInButton class? Also is the facebook button renderer identical?

Comment: The SignInButton class is the one from the Xamarin Google iOS SignIn package. Official API references at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in_button